When passing a pointer to a function in c, what actually happens?
I am trying to learn linked lists. In this I need to use a double pointer to pass by reference. But I am wondering, when we pass a pointer to the function, aren't we sending a copy of the address to the variable we are pointing to, to the function?
In this example:
struct node * delete(struct node* head)
{
//body of node deletion in linked list
}


int main()
{
struct node * head=NULL;
delete(head);
}

When I am passing the head, isn't it actually the address to the head that is passed? So when head is manipulated inside the delete function shouldn't it be reflected inside the main too without using a double pointer? Or is it creating a variable with same address that has its lifetime only inside the function? Can address be copied when pass by value? Isn't it a memory address which should only occur once? I am not fighting the concept, but just not clear about it.

Q: When I am passing the head, isn't it actually the address to the head that is passed? A: No. Read the duplicate.

Sorry didnt see that post before and thanks for pointing out
